# Top 10 event duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
TimeStamp (datetime)| Alarm (string) | Active (bool)
01.08.2013 1:30:05    | Alarm 1             | false
01.08.2013 1:29:54    | Alarm 2             | true
01.08.2013 1:28:43    | Alarm 1             | true
01.08.2013 1:27:21    | Alarm 3             | false
01.08.2013 1:26:35    | Alarm 1             | false
01.08.2013 1:25:34    | Alarm 1             | true
```

I already display the top 10 alarm occurrences:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Alarm, COUNT(Alarm) AS Occurrence
FROM MyTable
WHERE (Active = 'True')
GROUP BY Alarm
ORDER BY Occurrence DESC
```

I need now the top 10 alarm duration

The goal is to have the sum of duration (from true to false) for each individual alarm.

I'm really blocked on this, I guess that I need to iterate each row and sum time value for each met alarms.

But I don't know how to do that with a SQL query. Any help or direction will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

---

@Roman Pekar: SQL server 2008

@ Gordon Linoff: Output expected => top 10 alarm duration (when an alarm is true))

```
time[min] | Alarm

50 | Alarm 2
34 | Alarm 3
22 | Alarm 1

...
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Please provide sample output.  It is not clear what you want the result to be for the data in the question.

Comment: And how can you calculated the time for alarm 2 and 3 since there is only one occurrence of each (Alarm 2 = 1 true and Alarm 3 = 1 false) ? Also, for Alarm 1, do you want 2 lines or only 1. I mean, you want to calculate the total duration or both duration, 1:25:34 to 1:26:35, and then 1:28:43 to 1:30:05 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to find the first `off` after an `on`:

```
select  top 10 active.Alarm
,       active.TimeStamp as TimeOn
,       active.TimeStamp as TimeOff
,       datediff(second, active.TimeStamp, inactive.TimeStamp) as Duration
from    YourTable active
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    YourTable inactive
        where   inactive.Active = 'false'
                and inactive.Alarm = active.Alarm
                and inactive.TimeStamp > active.TimeStamp
        order by
                inactive.TimeStamp
        ) inactive
where   active.Active = 'true'
order by
        Duration desc
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a0e5/9/0)

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer, it help me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which may be more efficient.

```
;with a as
(
    select a.Alarm
    , a.Active
    , a.[Timestamp]
    , Sequence = dense_rank() over
                 (
                     partition by a.Alarm, a.Active
                     order by a.[TimeStamp]
                 )
    from #YourTable a
),
b as
(
    select a.Alarm
    , Start = b.[Timestamp]
    , Stop = a.[Timestamp]
    from a 
    left outer join a b
    on b.Alarm = a.Alarm
    and b.Sequence = a.Sequence
    and b.Active = 'true'
    where a.Active = 'false'
)
select b.Alarm
, DurationMinutes = sum(datediff(millisecond, b.Start, b.Stop) / 1000.0 / 60.0)
from b
group by b.Alarm
```

Comment: Might be more efficient, but also demands higher data consistency.  If the first row is the end of a previous alarm (an "off" entry) your query will return negative durations.

Comment: @Andomar True. You can add 'and b.Timestamp < a.Timestamp' to the 'on' clause for added rigour.